# Capture LLDP packets using tcpdump

Tags: tcpdump, packet-capture

What is the format to capture LLDP packets on an interface using tcpdump?

I tried the following format but it dint work:

```
tcpdump -w test.pcap -i eth0 lldp -vv
```

Answer (score 43, accepted):

```
tcpdump -w test.pcap -i eth0 ether proto 0x88cc
```

The Ethernet type for LLDP is 0x88cc, so the filter to see only LLDP packets is `ether proto 0x88cc`.

`-v` is useful when used with `-w` to print a short count of packets matched, like this: `Got 11`.

`-w` means "write the raw packets to the file, and don't print anything"; `-v` means "print verbosely", so ostensibly the arguments don't make sense together but with `-w`, the `-v` option provides some utility.

Comment: To be fair, `-v` is quite useful in combination with `-w` -- it makes tcpdump print the number of packets captured (there is a line saying `Got #` which keeps updating). Without `-v` you only know how many packets were captured at the end of the capture. Until then you are completely blind.

Comment: This was helpful to me for excluding LLDP traffic with tcpdump. Thanks!

Comment: the needed magic in my case was `ether proto 0x88cc` or rather `not ether proto 0x88cc`